# Long post titles don't move to next line

Tags: css

As you can see in the post title at http://fosit.staging.wpengine.com/, when the post title gets to the margin it doesn't continue on a new line; it continues on the *same* line.

I don't know if this problem is native to twenty twelve or if it's due a change I made to the child theme (like when I moved the date of the post from after the post to under the title).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to addition of following line in your child theme. There should be some line height to show header properly.

```
.entry-header .entry-title {
    font-size: 1.6000rem;       /* was 1.42857rem; */
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 0;            /* changed from 1.2 */   
}
```

Comment: Ah! Changing line height back to 1.2 fixes the problem. But it reminded me of why I changed it in the first place: it also affects the space between the title and the date of the post. Reducing the line height of `footer.entry-meta { line-height: 0; }` helps a bit, but I would still like to minimize the space between the post title and the date.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following css to your style-sheet (style.css).

```
.entry-header .entry-title{
    display: inline !important;
    line-height: 1 !important;
}
```

I've tested this by inspecting the website and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

you just needs to remove line-height then your issue will be fixed.

[image]